# Как происходит регистрация?

Tags: php, mysql

Когда пользователь уже зарегистрировался и прошла валидация. Когда сайт просит ввести логин и пароль. Пользователь вводит, как там лог и пароль проверяется?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как-то так:

```
if  ( !(
      preg_match( "/^[a-z\d-]{6,15}$/i", $_REQUEST['login'] ) &&
      preg_match( "/^[a-z\d-]{6,15}$/i", $_REQUEST['pass'] )
    )  ) echo 'regexp error';
else {
  $res_login = mysql_query(
    'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = "'.$_REQUEST['login'].'"'
  );
  if ( mysql_num_rows( $res_login ) != 1 ) echo 'login error';
  else{
    $row_login = mysql_fetch_array( $res_login );
    if ( $row_login['pass'] != $_REQUEST['pass'] ) echo 'password error';
    else {
      //Пользователь авторизован
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Можно пожалуйста объяснить словами?

Comment: Уже вижу ошибку синтаксиса)

Comment: Словами это так

( preg_match( "/^[a-z\d-]{6,15}$/i", $_REQUEST['login'] ) проверяем правильно ли введен логин, так же и про пароль.

Дальше просто проверка выборки из БД по логину и паролю + вывод сообщений.

Comment: @Palmervan, исправил)

@Zow, :

1. Проверяем переданные **login** и **pass** на соответствие нашему формату
2. Проверяем есть-ли пользователь с данным **login**
3. Проверяем совпадение **pass** с хранимым паролем

Comment: Не забывайте про хеширование файла. md5 к примеру.

Comment: что означает 
( mysql_num_rows( $res_login ) != 1 ) ?

Comment: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php

Если в БД не найдена запись, то значит такого логина нет.